# Styling javafx alertbox without css strings

Tags: javafx

How can I change JavaFX alertbox background without using css strings?. I mean something like Node.setStyle(-fx-background-color: red;)

Comment: Why do you want to do it without CSS? That's the supported approach.

Comment: What is "alertbox"?

Comment: you can make a custom dialog but it'll may require css .